# How to run telegram bot On IIS

Tags: c#, iis, telegram-bot

Hi I using this [Framework](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Telegram.Bot/) and [Project](https://github.com/TelegramBots/telegram.bot.examples) to Create my telegram bot

But this example is console application and I need to Lanch my Project on IIS

How can I upload my Project on IIS?

Comment: May i ask you why do you want to do that?

Comment: A bot is usually designed to be always running, monitoring for events and reacting at those events. I wonder if you are considering that. I would personally consider using a console app or windows service (first choice) as a project type.

Comment: I have to launch my Bot On Host
and On host I can't Run Any WinApplication

Comment: You Should Run your bot on mvc Project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Should Create MVC Project
and write all of your code in `Global.asax`

and then Lunch your Project On IIS

It Work For Evere

```
using Menu;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using Telegram.Bot;
using Telegram.Bot.Args;
using Telegram.Bot.Types;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.InlineKeyboardButtons;
using Telegram.Bot.Types.ReplyMarkups;


namespace TelegramMVC
{
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {

        Telegram.Bot.TelegramBotClient Bot = new TelegramBotClient("my_api_key");

        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

            Bot.OnMessage += Bot_OnMessage;
            Bot.StartReceiving();
        }

        private void Bot_OnMessage(object sender, MessageEventArgs messageEventArgs)
        {
            var message = messageEventArgs.Message;

            if (message == null || message.Type != MessageType.TextMessage) return;

            if (message.Text.Contains("/start")) 
            {
                string Str = "Start Recived";
                Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, Str, replyMarkup: MainMenu.ShowMenu(message));

            }
            else if (message.Text.Contains("/Stop"))
            {
                string Str = "Stop Recived";
                Bot.SendTextMessageAsync(message.Chat.Id, Str, replyMarkup: FollowerMenu.ShowFollowerMenu(message));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: thanks , I Used it,